# How to check whether the first array entry is empty in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The below VBA code sets a range of cells as commentArray, removes any blanks from the array and creates a new, blank free array, called commentResults. I then want to declare the array.

There is a possibility, depending on my source data, that the array could then still be empty so the below doesn't work to declare

```
thisws.Cells(i, 19).Resize(columnsize:=UBound(commentResults) - LBound(commentResults) + 1).Value = commentResults
```

So I thought I would add a check (the if statement after the debug.print), that only declared the array if array(0) wasn't empty but I continuously get an error 9 which I can't resolve.

```
Dim commentArray(4) As Variant
    commentArray(0) = Cells(24, 4).Value
    commentArray(1) = Cells(25, 3).Value
    commentArray(2) = Cells(26, 3).Value
    commentArray(3) = Cells(27, 3).Value

'a and b as array loops
Dim a As Long, b As Long
Dim commentResults() As Variant

'loops through the array to remove blanks - rewrites array without blanks into commentArray
For a = LBound(commentArray) To UBound(commentArray)
    If commentArray(a) <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim Preserve commentResults(b)
        commentResults(b) = commentArray(a)
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next a

Debug.Print b

If IsError(Application.Match("*", (commentResults), 0)) Then
Else
    thisws.Cells(i, 19).Resize(columnsize:=UBound(commentResults) - LBound(commentResults) + 1).Value = commentResults
    b = 0
End If
```

Any thoughts on why this might not work?

I have also tried:

```
If commentResults(0) <> vbNullString Then
    thisws.Cells(i, 27).Resize(columnsize:=UBound(commentResults) - LBound(commentResults) + 1).Value = commentResults
End If
```

Comment: Why not just check `If b > 0`?  (Also, since `Redim` is an "expensive" operation - expecially `Redim Preserve` would it be better to run the loop twice, once to count `b`, then `Redim` - `Preserve` unnecessary - and then loop again to populate it?)

Comment: @Chronocidal brilliant! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CommentArray()

Dim Comments As Range, c As Range
Set Comments = Union(Cells(24, 4), Range(Cells(25, 3), Cells(27, 3)))

Dim commentResults() As Variant
Dim i As Long

i = 0
For Each cell In Comments
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve commentResults(i)
        commentResults(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell

Dim debugStr As String

For i = LBound(commentResults) To UBound(commentResults)
    debugStr = debugStr & commentResults(i) & Chr(10)
Next i

MsgBox debugStr

End Sub
```

[image]